# Order of operations of multiple Matrix Elementary Row Operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two elementary row operation matrices (elimination matrices):

$E_{31} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$ (adds row $1$ to row $3$)

$E_{13} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$ (adds row $3$ to row $1$)

Am I correct in saying that if I *first* want $E_{31}$ applied and *second* want $E_{13}$ applied to a matrix, it is written as $E_{13}E_{31}$? I think of it as $E_{13}(E_{31}M)$.

My homework question asks **what $3$ by $3$ matrix adds row $1$ to row $3$ and *then* adds row $3$ to row $1$**:

[image: Question]

I thought the answer was $E_{13}E_{31}$; that is, $E_{31}$ (adds row 1 to row 3) gets applied first, and then $E_{13}$ (adds row 3 to row 1) gets applied after.

The book's answer is:

[image: Answer]

You can get the book's answer by multiplying $E_{13}$ with the matrix $E_{31}$.

Why did I get the wrong answer? I have used this same logic to correctly answer previous questions involving the order of multiplying two EROs.

---

This question is $\#10$ in Section 2.2 of **Introduction to Linear Algebra** by *Gilbert Strang*, *4th edition*. According to the answer below, the book's solution has a misprint. The matrix presented isn't wrong, but the two E matrices multiplied to make that step is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I added the _(adds row 1 to row 3)_ to point out that the subscripts are reversed. Like, $E_{xy}$ means _first_ y and _then_ x.

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour He still got the other answers right. I guess it's most likely that the book has this one wrong.

Comment: @Jason Why don't you try multiplying your matrix by an arbitrary $3\times 3$ matrix and check who's right?

Comment: You mean multiplying $E_{13}E_{31}$ (my answer) with some random 3 by 3 matrix $M$?

Comment: @Jason Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: What book is it? It's good to let the community knows what books have what misprints.

Comment: @Jason You multiplied them on the wrong side. Should be on the left.

Comment: @Jason The order that you're doing these operations isn't correct.

Comment: @Jason I have posted an answer for you.

Comment: @Jason By the way: \cdot to get $\cdot$ and \cdots to get $\cdots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is $E_{13}E_{31}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=P$ (say). You said that the book's answer is $E_{31}E_{13}=P$. If the book literally says that, then it is *correct* in that $P$ is the answer, but it is also *wrong* because $P=E_{13}E_{31}$, **not** $P=E_{31}E_{13}$. Since I don't have the book at hand, it's hard to say if the book is wrong or you have quoted the book wrongly.

Comment: The line that starts with "_The book's answer is_", the words and matrix after that is exactly pixel for pixel what the solutions has. No other letters before or after.

Comment: Just kidding, it says "Test on the identity matrix!" after that. But does that mean anything?

Comment: @Jason Then as I said, it is correct that $P$ is the answer, but it is wrong that $E_{31}E_{13}=P$. As to testing on $I_3$, he means if the two elementary matrices are multiplied in the opposite order, you will get a wrong result that is easy to spot.

Comment: What is "P(say)"? By the way, I've uploaded images of the book's question and answer.

Comment: @Jason It means "let us call this 3-by-3 matrix $P$".

Comment: Also, I think I'm not understanding $E_{13}E_{31}$ anymore. What is the order of multiplying those two matrices on a matrix $A$? Is it $E_{13} * E_{31} * A$? Or $E_{31} * E_{13} * A$? Or $A * E_{13} * E_{31}$? Or $A * E_{31} * E_{13}$?

Comment: @Jason The correct order is $PA=E_{13}E_{31}A$. So, if you test it on $A=I$, the result is $P$, which is exactly what you get if you add row 1 of $I$ to row $3$, and then add back row $3$ to row 1.

Comment: I was finally able to reproduce this correct solution. Thank you for all your help.